# Where to Obtain an Expansive Thunderbolt 3 Port Expander Suitable for Mobile Use With a MacBook Pro w/ Touch Bar and Touch ID?

Tags: laptop, hub, thunderbolt

Where might I find or commission a pre-made or custom-order a rather fully featured port-expansion hub or dock-like accessory designed to nest neatly underneath a 15-inch MacBook Pro with Touch Bar and Touch ID like the one I plan to order soon?  Specifically, I'm looking for a device with a complement of ports and media slots similar, but not identical, to that found on [Sonnet's Echo 15+ Thunderbolt 2 Dock](http://www.sonnettech.com/product/echo15thunderboltdock.html), but which interfaces with the aforementioned laptop using Thunderbolt 3 rather than its predecessor.  Here are the kinds of connectors and slots I would like to have on such a device:

- FireWire 400
- FireWire 800
- Mini DisplayPort/Thunderbolt 1 and 2
- USB 3.1 Gen. 2 Type C/Thunderbolt 3 passthrough
- USB 3.1 Gen. 2 Type A
- Gigabit Ethernet
- SDSC/-HC/-XC card reader
- A slot-loading optical drive capable of reading and writing to and from the following formats (basically, the same list of formats as the Sonnet dock I mentioned earlier:)

  - Bluray Disc (variants:

    - single- and double-layer BD-R
    - triple- and quadruple-layer BD-R XL
    - single- and double-layer BD-RE
    - triple- and quadruple-layer BD-RE XL
    - BD-ROM)
  - DVD (variants:

    - DVD-RAM
    - single- and double-layer DVD±R
    - DVD±RW
    - DVD-ROM)
  - CD (variants:

    - CD-R
    - CD-RW
    - CD-ROM)

The optical drive should support booting from discs as well, as one would probably expect.  In addition, I wouldn't mind also having access to the following additional functionality in such a device:

- An internal battery bank for battery lifetime extension
- Space for additional solid-state storage

Does anybody know what kind of place might supply or custom-build such a product to or for me?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit your question into a more simplified form?  Such as:  I am looking for X device, with A,B,C,D,E requirements....in a list or bullet list format?  Also please include your budget.   The way this is now, it is almost impossible to read and includes information that is not needed.

Comment: Also, this might be a suitable question for the Askdifferent stack, which is Apple-centric.

Comment: @NZKshatriya on your first comment:  Sorry, I'll work on fixing that tomorrow (I'm going to bed soon-ish.)

Comment: @NZKshatriya on your second comment:  True, but I tend to see more software- and OS-related stuff on there when I visit, so I thought this StackOverflow might turn out to be more appropriate (I'm probably just not looking hard enough, though, TBH/LOL…)

Comment: @NZKshatriya:  Sorry for the delay in editing this post to make it read more smoothly; got waylaid with some other stuff.  I fully intend to come back to this, though, so don't worry!

Comment: @NZKshatriya:  OK, post (finally, sorry!) edited.  Given my question's current form, however, I now agree that my post might indeed find a better home at Ask Different.  As such, how, then, would I go about getting this migrated over there if you and other possible answerers of this question end up in definite agreement on this?

Comment: @ Hrmm, That would require a moderator I think, I am just a *cough* humble *cough* user.  Mods are the ones with diamonds next to the name.

Comment: @NZKshatriya:  Ah, sure.  Better leave moving this question up to them, then.

Comment: For further/future reference, something like [OWC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Other_World_Computing)'s relatively new [DEC](https://www.owcdigital.com/dec), but with more ports and a spot for a slot-loading optical disc drive, might fit the bill very nicely.